# Comparison Ignoring Leading Characters

Tags: java, string-comparison

I receive strings of the form "0000A", "00000000A", "0A".  They can have many or no leading zeros.  I want them to evaluate as equal ignoring the leading zeros.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @matt b's suggestion, you can do

```
if(text1.replaceAll("^0+","").equals(text2.replaceAll("^0+",""))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. remove any leading zeros
2. test the equality of the remaining strings

Answer (score 0):

To avoid buffer copies by a regex engine, you can check whether one string is a suffix of the other using `regionMatches` and then check that the prefix of the longer is all zeroes.

```
if (a.regionMatches(
    Math.max(0, a.length() - b.length()),
    b, Math.max(0, b.length() - a.length()),
    Math.min(a.length(), b.length())) {
  // Check whether the prefix that is not common to both is all zeroes.
}
```